# Integration Widget (GWT) with DynamicForm (Smartgwt) - com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException

Tags: gwt, widget, smartgwt, detach

I had this problem when I created a Window (Smartgwt) and put a DynamicForm (Smartgwt) in this Window, In this DynamicForm, I have a CanvasItem (Smartgwt) in which I put a RichTextArea (GWT). And when I press "ESC", I can quit the Window (Smartgwt) without probleme. But when I press "F5" to refresh my application, the browser pops up a exception saying `"com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AttachDetachException"`. To solve this problem, I do the following:

```
public class MailWindow extends Window {
    public MailWindow(){
    this.addCloseClickHandler(new CloseClickHandler() {  
            public void onCloseClick(CloseClientEvent event) {
                form.getRichTextArea().removeFromParent();
                MailWindow.this.destroy();
            }  
        });  
    }
}
```

Which solved my problem! :)

Kewei

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting this. We'll try to incorporate the logic in SmartGWT itself so that you don't need to explicitly call removeFromParent()